# Generating Logarithmically Spaced Values on an Operation Limited Microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, logarithm

I've recently come across a problem where, using a cheap 16 bit uC (MSP430 series), I've had to generate a logarithmically spaced output value based on the 10 bit ADC read. The reason for this is that I require fine grain control at the low end of the integer space, while, at the same time, requiring the use of the larger values, though at less precision, (to me, the difference between 2^15 and 2^16 in my feedback loop is of little consequence). I've never done this before and I had no luck finding examples online, so I came up with a little scheme to do this on my operation-limited uC.

With my method here, the ADC result is linearly interpolated between the two closest integer powers-of-two via only integer multiplication/addition/summation and bitwise shifting, (outlined below).

My question is, is there a better, (faster/less operations), way than this to generate a smooth, (or smooth-ish), set of data logarithmically spaced over the integer resolution? I haven't found anything online, hence my attempt at coming up with something from scratch in the first place.

N is the logarithmic resolution of the micro controller, (here assumed to be 16 bit). M is the integer resolution of the ADC, (here assumed to be 10 bit). ADC_READ is the value read by the ADC at a given time. On a uC that supports floating point operations, doing this is trivial:

```
x = N / M  #16/1024
y = (float) ADC_READ / M   #ADC_READ/1024
result = 2 ^ ( x * y )
```

In all of the plots below, this is the "Ideal" set of values. The "Resultant" values are generated by variations of the following:

```
unsigned int returnValue( adcRead ){

    unsigned int e;
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int rise;
    unsigned int base;
    unsigned int xoffset;
    unsigned int yoffset;

    e = adcRead >> 6;
    a = 1 << e;

    rise = ( 1 << (e + 1) )  - ( 1 << e );
    base = e << 6;

    xoffset = adcRead - base;
    yoffset = ( rise >>  rise_shift ) * (xoffset >> offset_shift);  //this is an operation to prevent rolling over.   rise_shift + offset_shift = M/N, here = 6

    result = a + yoffset;
    return result;
}
```

The extra declarations and what not are for readability only. Assume the final product is condensed. Basically, it does as intended, with varying degrees of discretization at the low end and smoothness at the high end based on the values of rise_shift and offset_shift. Here, they are both equal to 3:
[image: rise >> 3, offset >> 3]
Here rise_shift = 2, offset_shift = 4
[image: rise >> 2, offset >> 4]
Here rise_shift = 4, offset_shift = 2
[image: rise >> 4, offset >> 2]
I'm interested to see if anyone has come up with or knows of anything better. Currently, I only have to run this code ~20-30 times a second, so I obviously have not encountered any delays. But, with a 16MHz clock, and using information from [here](http://www2.ife.ee.ethz.ch/~roggend/publications/wear/DSPMic_v1.1.pdf), I estimate this entire operation taking at most ~110 clock cycles, or ~7us. This is on the scale the ADC read time, which is ~4us.

Thanks

EDIT:  By "better" I do not necessarily just mean faster, (it's already quite fast, apparently). Immediately, one sees that the low end has fairly drastic discretization to the integer powers of two, which results from the shifting operations to prevent roll-ever. Other than a look-up table, (suggested below), the answer to how this could be improved is not immediate.

Comment: Very interesting post! Unfortunately no time to dive in at the moment.

Comment: Could you show the show a complete C function you want to speed up?  This would help understand the exact question, instead of having to understand your problem first, and then deduce what you'd need.

Comment: You have illustrated an exponential curve, but described how your requirement is a logarithm. Which do you need? Is it already working with the exponential? Clearly the illustrated function loses precision at the low end, not the high end.

Comment: @Potatoswatter sorry I thought I was clear. The requirement is fine grain control at the lower end of the integer space while still being able to select the very high end. Imagine I need to program a delay. I want to be able to program  100us, 200us, 300us,  etc, but I ALSO would like to program 5 seconds, for example. My requirement is an exponential, but the ADC read is treated as logarithmically spaced rather than linearly.@meaning-matters  I've wrapped my code into a function.

Comment: @SteveNovakov You're still giving more high-level requirements. Two things matter: 1. What is the source code you have now, and 2. Does it function correctly, aside from performance. Aside from that, there's too much noise in this question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I believe I've made it more clear, the problem I'm looking to address is the discretization at the low end. Sorry if it was too vague, I wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: @SteveNovakov Most of the low-end discretization is a result of the mathematical function you chose. That's what an exponential *does*, which is why it sounds like you really want a logarithm instead, which is the complete opposite. Still your implementation introduces additional discretization, and I have given an answer which minimizes this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> based on the 10 bit ADC read.

This ADC can output only 1024 different values (0-1023), so you can use a table of 1024 16-Bit values, which would consume 2KB Flash memory:

```
const uint16_t LogarithmicTable[1024] = { 0, 1, ... , 64380};
```

Calculating the logarithmic output is now a simple array access:

```
result =  LogarithmicTable[ADC_READ];
```

You can use a tool like Excel to generate the constants in this Table for you.

Comment: Yeah a lookup table is a fast solution, I had thought about that, I won't mark this as the answer yet I'd like to see what people suggest, but it is likely the fastest and I agree that 2KB is not a lot, UNLESS you have a large amount of code. I actually have hit "size walls" with this particular series of micro, (though, arguably I do try to squeeze them into roles that should probably be taken up by larger, faster alternatives). Thanks Turbo.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compute the function 2<sup>n/64</sup>, which would map 1024 to 65536 just above the high end but maps anything up to 64 to zero (or one, depending on rounding). Other exponential functions could avoid the low-end discretization, but it's not clear whether that would help the functionality.

We can factor 2<sup>n/64</sup> into 2<sup>floor( n/64 )</sup> × 2<sup>(n mod 64)/64</sup>. Usually multiplying by an integer power of 2 involves a left shift, but because the other side is a fraction between one and two, we're better off doing a right shift.

```
uint16_t exp_table[ 64 ] = {
        32768u,
        pow( 2, 1./64 ) * 32768u,
        pow( 2, 2./64 ) * 32768u,
        ...
};

uint16_t adc_exp( uint16_t linear ) {
    return exp_table[ linear % 64 ] >> ( 15 - linear / 64 );
}
```

This loses no precision against a full, 2-kilobyte table. To save more space, use linear interpolation.

Comment: Sorry did you mean   return exp_table[ linear % 64] >> (15 - (linear/64))? That would make sense, just making sure. It is a good space saving strategy, but, as stated, some uC series do not support integer divide. Though, I could replace (linear/64), with (linear>>6), to be sure. I just plotted this and I get some real funky behaviour, might be error on my end though.

Comment: @SteveNovakov Yeah, woops missing parens. My intent is that the compiler replaces the modulo with bit-and and the divide with bit-shift.